# 就要 contraction juo?

Tags: grammar

There's a commercial that plays on TV everyday now where in the lyrics 就要 is sung as `juo`. 就要就要 is sung as `juo juo`. There's nothing in my dictionaries alluding to a 就要 contraction and I've not been able to find anything online talking about it. My hunch is that it is just a rhyming technique to make the lyrics sound better.

The video can be found here: http://www.iqiyi.com/w_19rtxh9rel.html `就要就要` starts at about ~0:19.

Is this an actual thing anywhere?

Comment: Any audio/video we can listen to?

Comment: Music doesn't have to articulate everything word. Rhyme might be a far more important factor. Think about songs by Jay Chou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have such contraction normally. I think this is just for rhyme since most of the lyrics contain word 拼多多(pinduoduo) which ends with "uo". If the singer sings 就要(jiuyao) as "juo", it will also end with "uo". And this make the singing sounds quite cute, at least in my opinion.